# Liquid simulation looks weird. Strange patterns

Tags: fluid-simulation

I`m new to Blender and I have a issue with my liquid simulation.

I tried to make a glass of water, but the water acts more like jelly when its in the glass. It would look more natural if the water became invisible and only the surface was visible.

It seems to escape the glass as well. Any suggestions?

[Video of the issue](https://youtu.be/wvWXWceBPGs):

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: ok. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You should have diffusion turned on with those setting for water, if you have higher base your symulation will look more like honey or katchup, or like jelly in your case. Also material should have 0 roughness and 100% transition, and IOR set to 1.(33)

sett up: https://gyazo.com/aef5a4bec7dbd5baf17834b559ea81da